# Where to a place a custom php file in the directory

Tags: forms

I have a hard coded form that i need to send to a php page that i have built. With drupal i am a bit confused on where i would place this php page so it doesnt cause any problems.

I was thinking here but i wanted to check first.
/httpdocs/newsite/PHP-HERE
(Same directory as index.php)

Where would i place this php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything including forms can be integrated nicely within drupal. i would recommend reviewing FAPI. it will save you time/effort in the end.

however, if you absolutely need this not to be built around/within/whatever using drupal's FAPI, what i would do is put the page either directly in your theme folder or make a subfolder and drop it in there. so lets make many assumptions here (awful i know). say your form is called newform.php. rename it to `page-newform.tpl.php` and drop it into one of those folders. create a page just to give you a node place holder and a path like /newform. then in your template.php file under the `THEMENAME_preprocess_page()` function, check the URL with either `$_GET['q']` or `arg()` (arg is preferred). if the url is going to /newform simply adjust your `$variables['template_file']` to be something like `$variables['template_file'] = 'page-newform'`. this will pick up your page specifically.

so with a lot of assumptions and very little go on with what you are doing. this could be done.

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
 if (arg(0) == 'newform') {
   $variables['template_file'] = 'page-newform'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want your form to be tied to Drupal. If it must insert data in the database, you'd better use [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to generate and manage it.

If you're sure your data is totally independant from Drupal, you can manage your form with custom functions in a module, but it will be work and you wont get any benefit from drupal's power.

An alternative would be to use [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform).

Answer (score 0):

I would put it into a pseudo-module and place it in

```
DRUPALROOT/sites/all/modules/custom/YOURMODULEHERE
```

in your helper module you can also specify a menu hook, if the resulting URL would be too long or not attractive for your needs.